# Webpack: is there a loader that just ignores require() calls?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Consider a JavaScript file with some

```
require("some-module")
```

I want Webpack to just ignore the require and output it "as-is" to the resulting JS. This can be achieved with the [externals](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals) configuration parameter, but I would prefer some inline annotation like

```
require("emit-this-as-is-loader!some-module")
```

Background: I need to create a node.js-targeted output which requires() many auto-generated files (these are generated during and after the Webpack build phase, so they can't be injected using the corresponding content loaders). Specifying all these auto-generated files as 'externals' clutters my config and is error prone, as each require() to an auto-generated file only appears once.

Is there any way to do this without re-inventing the will and writing a custom loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`external-loader`](https://github.com/sheerun/external-loader), which would give you the opportunity to define externals in place, at the point of reference:

```
const script = require('external-loader!./script');
```

Contrast this to specifying all your externals with `configuration.externals` in advance, before the compiler instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `target` config parameter help here Here is the documentation for it: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target

Comment: I'm already setting the target, but this does not have any impact on resolving require() calls